# jQuery cycle2 after function

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle2

How can we add after, before call back  function in new jQuery cycle ,
Links here http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2

I do work with jQuery cycle(old version) but i dont know how to implement cycle2(new version)

http://jsfiddle.net/3vjgJ/2/

Examples jQuery code of old version cycle (check after function code )

```
$('#mySlideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
     after: function() {
        $('ul li').removeClass('test');
        $(this).addClass('test') 
    }
});

<ul id="mySlideshow" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-slides="li" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-prev=".prev" data-cycle-next=".next">
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
</ul>
<a href=# class="prev">Prev</a>
<a href=# class="next">Next</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Read the manual. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: @putvande  Can you update jsfiddle , please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cycle2 is different to Cycle if you read to FAQ bit on the website.
In Cycle2 `after` function is being not used anymore.
If you add the following line to your code it should work:

```
$('#mySlideshow').on('cycle-after',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
    $('ul li').removeClass('test');
    $(incomingSlideEl).addClass('test') 
});
```

You can remove the

```
after: function() {
    $('ul li').removeClass('test');
    $(this).addClass('test') 
}
```

Also, Cycle2 works without adding the `$('#mySlideshow').cycle({ .. })` bit.

So you can just have

```
$('#mySlideshow').on('cycle-after',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
    $('ul li').removeClass('test');
    $(incomingSlideEl).addClass('test') 
});
```

and everything should work. http://jsfiddle.net/3vjgJ/12/

Comment: i am trying add/remove class "test", it should work on items (<li> tag), Any idea ?

Comment: And im guessing you want to remove `test` from all `<li>` tags and add the `test` to the current `<li>` right? I have edit my answer, have a look. It should work this way.

Comment: You are right , but its not working , I have checked in firebug

Comment: Did the fiddle not work? I saw there was a bit of code missing in it. Have updated the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/3vjgJ/12/